# How can I setup Django and React on the same port and handle routing?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-router

## The Problem

Hi! I’m trying to setup my Django-React app but I can’t manage to get both to run in the same port (Django Rest API is in port `8000` and react in `3000`) using the react router links and routes.

I am using `django, djangorestframework, react, react router` and `react router dom`. Please help

Django's API works perfectly for get and post requests and they load perfectly with `ListCreateAPIView`s

Here are some pictures of my files. Let me know if you need any more info.

## The Pictures

### Project Structure

[image: Project Structure]

### models.py

[image]

### serializers.py

[image]

### api/urls.py

[image]

### urls.py

[image]

### settings.py

[image]

Comment: Change the port in webpack or change the port you're running the django server with to whatever port you want. That said, if you are developing/running both on the same machine, you want them running on different ports because only one application can be bound to any port so you can't run them on the same port at the same time

Comment: But eventually I want to run everything in a server and for that its better that everything runs in the same port right? Btw I also used create-react-app

Comment: Or is it ok for the production build to be run each in its own port?

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking and I let an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A port is a specific networking endpoint that is bound to an application instance running on the server. For example, typically if I want to connect to my server via ssh I will need to connect via port 22. Since SSH is running on port 22, nothing else can run there because how would the computer know if the traffic coming into port 22 was for ssh or the other application listening there? That is why there are thousands of ports that you can use and why django and react run on different ports if you are running them at the same time. If you're interested I'd read up a bit on [ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)) and some other basic networking topics.

Now I think what you're asking is: I want to run react and django together and I want them to be able to communicate. For this running in different ports is fine, for development just point the react app to communicate with django over the specified port and the same for django. When you actually go to launch an app in production, you will run the program on the server and bind it to a port then your clients will hit the api using that specified port. Because they aren't running on the same machine in production, there will be no collisions so this is fine. Sometimes you have the situation where lots of things try to connect at the same time and if something is already connected on that port, the connection will be refused. That is why webserver can be configured to listen on a specific port and forward traffic to others so many users can be serviced simultaneously.

Comment: Awesome answer! Also I hadn't rendered `index.html` in django for the main path. Everything is ok now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### THE ANSWER

This is not possible due to Django and React needing each one a separate port to run. In order for this to work a `build` from React must be generated and then imported and redered by Django so that only the django app is running and only the Django port is open.

Hope this helps anyone who had this question too.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can do if you set up [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) on your server and you the reverse proxy act as a router so you can do something link

localhost/api --> locahost:8000

localhost --> locahost:3000